# Subbundles of Direct Sum of Holomorphic Line Bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, holomorphic-bundles, line-bundles

Given a holomorphic line bundle $L$ on a Riemann surface $M\,,$ with $L^2$ nontrivial, when is it true that the only holomorphic subbundles of $$L\oplus L^{-1}$$ are $L\oplus\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\oplus L^{-1}\,?$. I have seen things like this stated for genus $\ge 2$ but I'm not sure how to see that it is  true.

Comment: In general, this is false. Given any rank two vector bundle, you can find line sub bundles of arbitrarily large (or should I say small?) negative degrees.